# Show title only if content

Tags: php, html, wordpress, title

I want to hide `<h2>title</h2>` if they are not **children pages**.

```
<h2> title</h2></br>

<?php
// Globalize the $post variable;
// probably already available in this context, but just in case...
global $post;

wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li'     => __(''), 
    // Only pages that are children of the current page
    'child_of' => $post->ID,
    // Only show one level of hierarchy
    'depth' => 1,
) );
?>
```

Comment: Can you add the code on how we can check if there are no children pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get_children function to get all child contents of your post. If the return array is empty, there are no child pages defined:

```
<?php
   $children =& get_children( 'post_type=page' );
   if (!empty($children)) "<h2> title</h2>";
?>
```

Documentation:

- get_children:
  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children
- Post types: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types